# Take a record to update and let no other update take and update that record during the process

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework to develop a website.

The problem I'm having here is a client select 1 record and update it, but if there is another client running the same select query the db will return the same record selected before and rewrite.

How do I avoid this? Is there anyway I can select a record and let no other touch that record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I avoid this. Is there anyway I can select a record and let no other touch that record?

You need to implmenent concurency management :

- your table must have a row version column. When users query the data you send row version along the data.
- each update from your user must include the row version.
- if the row version is different with the current value stored in the database then you throw an exception.
- if the row version is same with the one stored in your table then update the data and regenerate the row version column.

Entity Framework make it easy to handle concurrency just take a look at this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). It will help you a lot.